# Canvas HTML fillText letters to not animate only shadows

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Only want shadows to animate and keep the fillText from animating due to letters pixelating from getting ran over and over.

```js
    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas')
    var ctx = this.canvas.getContext('2d')
    var width = canvas.width = canvas.scrollWidth
    var height = canvas.height = canvas.scrollHeight
    var start;
    var j=0;
 var makeText = function(){  
    j+=1 

    ctx.shadowColor= 'red'; 
       ctx.shadowOffsetX = j;  //animate
    ctx.shadowOffsetY = j; //animate
    ctx.globalAlpha=0.5;
    ctx.font = "48px serif";
       ctx.fillStyle = "black";
       ctx.fillText('hey you', width/2, height / 2); //Only ran once so letters 
                                                     //don't pixelate!
   }
    
       
 function animateText(timestamp){
  var runtime = timestamp - start;
  var progress = Math.min(runtime / 1400, 1); 
 
  makeText(progress)
    
  if(progress < 1){
   requestAnimationFrame(animateText)
  }else {
   return;
  }
 }
 requestAnimationFrame(function(timestamp){
  start = timestamp;
  animateText(timestamp)
 })
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width=500px height=500px></canvas>
```

My outcome of the process would only have shadows animate and keeping letters where they are

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just draw your own shadows, here is an example:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas')
var ctx = this.canvas.getContext('2d')
ctx.font = "68px serif";
var base = {text: 'hey you', x: 10, y: 60 }
var inc = 2;
var j = 30;

var makeText = function() {
  ctx.globalAlpha = 1;
  ctx.fillStyle = "black";
  ctx.fillText(base.text, base.x, base.y); 
}

var makeshadow = function(offset) {
  ctx.fillStyle = "red";
  for (var i = 0; i < offset; i++) {
    ctx.globalAlpha = 1/i;
    ctx.fillText(base.text, base.x + i, base.y + i);
  }
}

function animateText() {  
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 999, 999)
  makeshadow(j);
  makeText();  
  j += inc;
  if (j > 35 || j < 3) inc *= -1
}

setInterval(animateText, 50)
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width=300px height=170px></canvas>
```

---

And if you add some math in the mix you can get some cool effects:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas')
var ctx = this.canvas.getContext('2d')
ctx.font = "68px serif";
var base = {text: '123456', x: 30, y: 80 }
var inc = 5;
var j = 0;

var makeText = function() {
  ctx.globalAlpha = 1;
  ctx.fillStyle = "black";
  ctx.fillText(base.text, base.x, base.y); 
}

var makeshadow = function(offset) {
  ctx.globalAlpha = 0.05;
  ctx.fillStyle = "red";
  for (var i = 0; i < offset; i++)
    ctx.fillText(base.text, base.x + Math.sin(i/5)*10, base.y + Math.cos(i/5)*15);
}

function animateText() {  
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 999, 999)
  makeshadow(j);
  makeText();  
  j += inc;
  if (j > 120 || j < 0) inc *= -1
}
setInterval(animateText, 50)
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width=300px height=170px></canvas>
```

Comment: I knew it was going to be as simple as that. Outstanding!

Comment: @BradVanderbush I'm glad I you see it simple, and once you know how to draw shadows you open the door for more advanced effects

Comment: if (j > 35 || j < 3) inc *= -1  simple and brilliant, I had to console.log it to figure out exactly how it made it a loop.

Comment: @BradVanderbush I'm glad you like it, I also added some effect to the globalAlpha that way it looks like the shadow is vanishing

Answer (score 1):

Your main issue (the text pixelisation) is due to you not clearing the canvas between every frames, and drawing again and again over the same position. semi-transparent pixels created by antialiasing mix up to more and more opaque pixels.

But in your situation, it seems that you actually want at-least the shadow to mix up like this.

To do it, one way would be to draw only once your normal text, and to be able to draw **only** the shadow, **behind** the current drawing.

---

#### Drawing only the shadow of a shape.

One trick to draw only the shadows of your shape is to draw your shape out of the visible viewPort, with shadowOffsets set to the inverse of this position.

```js
var text = 'foo bar';
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var original_x = 20; // the position it would have been

ctx.font = '30px sans-serif';

var targetPosition = ctx.measureText(text).width + original_x + 2;
// default shadow settings
ctx.shadowColor = 'red';
ctx.shadowBlur = 3;
// just to show what happens
var x = 0;
anim();

function anim() {
  if(++x >= targetPosition) {
    x=0;
    return;
  }
  // if we weren't to show the anim, we would use 'targetPosition'
  // instead of 'x'
  ctx.shadowOffsetX = x;
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
  ctx.fillText(text, -x + original_x, 30);
  requestAnimationFrame(anim);
}
// restart the anim on click
onclick = function() {
  if(x===0)anim();
};
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Once we have this clear shadow, without our shape drawn on it, we can redraw it as we wish.

---

#### Drawing behind the current pixels

The *"destination-over"* [compositing option](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/globalCompositeOperation) does just that.

So if we put these together, we can draw behind the normal text, and only draw our shadow behind it at each frame, avoiding antialiasing mix-up.

*(Note that we can also keep the clean shadow on an offscreen canvas for performances, since shadow is a really slow operation.)*

```js
var text = 'foo bar';
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
ctx.font = '48px sans-serif';
var x = 20;
var y = 40;
var shadow = generateTextShadow(ctx, text, x, y, 'red', 5);

ctx.globalAlpha = 0.5;
ctx.fillText(text, x, y);
// from now on we'll draw behind current content
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-over';

var shadow_pos = 0;
anim();
// in the anim, we just draw the shadow at a different offset every frame
function anim() {
  if(shadow_pos++ > 65) return;
  ctx.drawImage(shadow, shadow_pos, shadow_pos);

  requestAnimationFrame(anim);
}

// returns a canvas where only the shadow of the text provided is drawn
function generateTextShadow(original_ctx, text, x, y, color, blur, offsetX, offsetY) {
  var canvas = original_ctx.canvas.cloneNode();
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  ctx.font = original_ctx.font;
  var targetPosition = ctx.measureText(text).width + 2;
  // default shadow settings
  ctx.shadowColor = color || 'black';
  ctx.shadowBlur = blur || 0;
  ctx.shadowOffsetX = targetPosition + x +(offsetX ||0);
  ctx.shadowOffsetY = (offsetY || 0);
  ctx.fillText(text, -targetPosition, y);
  return canvas;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: The idea is to draw behind it. Filltext() first, then ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-over';  keeps from anything then on drawn over it?

Comment: @BradVanderbush yes destination over means that whatever non transparent pixels that are already drawn will be over the new ones, or more simply that next drawings will be done behind.